# a design through html and data taken from sql database using php and sql by using file_get_contents() and str_replace

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Actually i wanted to make a page in which a serach bar will be there like this[this is the main search page](https://uemk.000webhostapp.com/search.html) after typing the mobile number the searched result should be replaced in [in the place where there is ##% name %## ##% gender %## and so on](https://uemk.000webhostapp.com/searchcopy.html)

```
<?php
   $inpsearch = $_POST['search'];

  $servername = "localhost";
 $user = "";
  $password = "";
 $database = "";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$user,$password,$database);

// Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 
  else
 {
 $sql = "SELECT  firstname , lastname , gender , email , mobile , parent , 
parentmob , address , course FROM Students";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row["mobile"] == $inpsearch)
    {
        $name= $row['firstname']. " " .$row['lastname'];
        $template = file_get_contents("searchcopy.html");

$template = str_replace('##% name %##',$name,$template);
$template = str_replace('##% gender %##',$row['gender'],$template);
$template = str_replace('##% course %##',$row['course'],$template);
$template = str_replace('##% email %##',$row['email'],$template);
$template = str_replace('##% mobile %##',$row['mobile'],$template);
$template = str_replace('##% parent %##',$row['parent'],$template);
$template = str_replace('##% parentmob %##',$row['parentmob'],$template);
$template = str_replace('##% address %##',$row['address'],$template);

    }
}
    header('Location:https://uemk.000webhostapp.com/searchcopy.html');  

} else {
   echo "0 results";
  }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

this was my search.php
and this is my search.html and searchcopy.html 
there is not much different in searchcopy and search only ##% name %##' ##% course %##' and such things are extra

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>University Database (UEMK)</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon"  type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

  <!-- you should always add your stylesheet (css) in the head tag so that 
it starts loading before the page html is being displayed -->   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style>
       * {box-sizing: border-box;}

    .topnav input[type=text] {
    margin-left:35%;
padding: 6px;
margin-top: 2%;
font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav input[type=text] {
border: 1px solid #ccc;  
}
.topnav button[type=submit]
{
    background:#1F1275;
    color:white;
    padding:0.40%;  
    width:6%;
}
.container
{
margin:5% 15% 5% 15%;
    padding:5%;
    border:1px solid black;
    top:50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
        <div class="topnav">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search by mobile number..." name="search">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="container">


 <label><b>Full Name :</b> ##% name %## </label>
  <br><br>







    <label><b>Gender : </b> ##% gender %## </label>
   <br><br>


     <label><b>Course / Stream :</b> ##% course %## </label>

 <br><br>

  <label><b>Email :</b> ##% email %## </label>
  <br><br>


  <label><b>Mobile Number :</b> ##% mobile %##
 </label>
  <br><br>
    <label><b>Parent : </b> ##% parent %## </label>
 <br><br>


   <label><b>Parent's Mobile Number :</b> ##% parentmob %## </label>

  <br><br>
  <label><b>Address :</b> ##% address %## </label>
  <br><br> 
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the Line `header('Location:https://uemk.000webhostapp.com/searchcopy.html');` as it is redirecting the web page to load the webpage where there is no change. The `$template` variable is local to the php script and cannot be accessed if you are using the header function. What you need to do is `echo $template` and the browser will see that it is a html code and thus show the necessary data as a webpage.